# Should the identity labelled by red line be $\overline{f(Z)}=X$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

[image]

The above picture is from Milne's Etale Cohomology.

Suppose $A=\Bbb Z, \mathfrak q=(2T+3)$, consider $Z=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z[T]/(2T+3)\to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z[T]\to\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z$.  Then $f(Z)$ doesn't contain the prime ideal $(2)$.

Should the identity labelled by red line be $\overline{f(Z)}=X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be $\overline{f(Z)} = X$. In fact, $\mathfrak{q} \cap A = 0$ literally means that the image in $X$ of the generic point of the irreducible subset $Z \subseteq \mathbb{A}^1_X$ --which corresponds to the prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq A[T]$-- is equal to the generic point of $X = {\rm Spec}(A)$ (recall that $A$ is an integral domain). This implies that the composition $Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1_X \rightarrow X$ is dominant (i.e., the image is dense), which literally means that $\overline{f(Z)} = X$.

And as your example correctly shows, one does not need to have $f(Z) = X$ in general.